# What is a windowSplashscreenContent item in the styles.xml file in an Android project

Tags: android, splash-screen

`<item name="android:windowSplashscreenContent">#What comes here ?#</item>`

What are the valid values for this item in the styles.xml ?

Does this mean that to create a splash-screen, all you gotta do is set this item with some value ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#windowSplashscreenContent

Comment: Thank you, So adding a drawable to this item automatically creates a splash screen ?

Answer (score 0):

You would add a drawable:

`@drawable/splashscreen`

As shown in the commit here, the example at the bottom:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7d0d10275213f23e2bd200d22822a3b700157688%5E%21/

```
         <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/blue</item>
         <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue</item>
     </style>
+    <style name="CustomSplashscreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
+        <item name="android:windowSplashscreenContent">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
+    </style>
 </resources>
```